# c, correct use of threads

Tags: c, pthreads, grand-central-dispatch

when you create thread using thread_create and pass the function, does the function goes forever if there is infinite loop in the function?
eg

```
for(;;){
    //dosomthing
}
```

Does the thread keep "do somthing" until the thread is destroyed or the program is finished?

Thanx

Comment: Your question is lost in the sea of source code you are posting. If you remove all your superfluous code and ask about a clear concept you may have a bigger chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: I think you're showing a load of analogous, but irrelevant pthreads code. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: In the above example your program will run forever until the thread is terminated.  It depends what is inside the loop though.  If your parent thread wants to join it will block until this is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke thread_create() the thread that gets created will itself invoke the function you passed. So for example:

```
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_do, NULL);
```

will make a new thread and the new thread will run the function thread_do().
If now you have previously defined thread_do() as:

```
void* thread_do(){

  for(;;){
    // do something
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

then the thread will go to an endless loop indeed.